# How can I get the default Power BI Report Server branding zip file?

Tags: server, report, powerbi, branding

I need to change the default branding of our instance of Power BI Report Server (PBIRS).  I've read a few articles on how to do this (e.g. Guy in a cube do a good video on YouTube).  However, is it possible to get the current default settings?

I'd like to use the default settings as a starting point and also back them up in case I make a message of the UI.

I have seen default branding packages for SSRS but the colors are different for PBIRS.

Any ideas?  Thanks.